# Different textsize for spinner dropdown item and spinner selected item

Tags: android, spinner, font-size

Is there a way do define 2 different textsizes for a spinner?
What I want to have:
when the spinner is not clicked (no dropdown), the text size can be 'A' sp.
When the spinner is clicked, the text size of the items in the dropdown can be 'B' sp.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the different text sizes in the getDropDownView(...) and in the getView() methods.